# taking square using "value**2" results causes an overflow while "value*value" is fine

Tags: python, python-internals, python-hypothesis

Given the same input, `x**2` gives an integer overflow while `x*x` works fine.

I am not sure if this is because of the python's internal implementation of those operator or if this is a bug in the hypothesis package. Is the opcode for `x**2` different from the opcode of `x*x`?

Here's the minimal example to reproduce it. `value*value` passes but `value**2` fails.

```py
from typing import TypeVar

import pytest
from hypothesis import given, strategies as st

T = TypeVar("T", int, float)

def square2(i: T) -> T:
    return i*i

@given(
  st.one_of(
      st.integers(),
      st.floats(allow_nan=False),
    )
)
def test_square2(value):
    assert square2(value) == value*value
    assert square2(value) == value**2
```

output

```
    def test_square2(value):
        assert square2(value) == value*value
>       assert square2(value) == value**2
E       OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

This is discovered while working on this tutorial: https://github.com/seifertm/hypothesis-workshop/blob/main/exercises/tests/test_01_baby_steps.py

Comment: This test passes on my machine - can you show the *full* failing output, including the minimal failing example and the traceback?

Comment: Ok, I added a seed. Can you try with the seed?

```python
@seed(1234)
@given(
  st.one_of(
      st.integers(),
      st.floats(allow_nan=False),
    )
```

Comment: I'll put the traceback

Comment: Given the answer, the traceback is no longer needed I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just Python's standard semantics for `float`: overflow in multiplication returns `inf`, but overflow in exponentiation raises `OverflowError`.

Weird, but not a bug in Hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks, is there a more detailed documentation about these standard semantics?

Comment: Not that I can find, sorry!  You can check specifics in the repl I guess...